# How do you read a large file with a small buffer in assembly with system calls? Does read append a \0?

Tags: linux, assembly, file-io, x86-64, system-calls

Calling the read syscall for a file larger than the size of my buffer will mean the buffer will only capture the first part of the file. Trying to call it again will have no effect, it still only gives first part of the file. Say the file is 1 GB and the buffer is 1024 bytes, then we'll only ever access the first 1024 bytes of the large file. Is there any way to access the rest of the file without increasing the buffer size?

I couldn't find any flag talking about this when you open the file on this website: https://linuxhint.com/list_of_linux_syscalls/#open-flags (unless I misunderstood the descriptions).

I initially thought that the computer would fill the second 1024 bytes when I syscalled for the second time (like it is in C IIRC). Well, really I had a text file size of ~1300B and a buffer size of 512B, so it isn't an issue for me to resize in this case, but I wanted to know how it was dealt with in general.

Is there some kind of other syscall to break the file into pieces or to make it into some kind of stream-like object? I know there's a bash split command. How do C and my OS deal with files like this? C has an option to eat a file with one bite at a time, are they really using a very large buffer underneath? It feels wasteful to be forced to have the full file copied into a separate buffer and I would be surprised if there was no alternative.

EDIT: Sorry! It turns out there was no problem with any syscall, what happened was that I expected there to be a null byte or some other special character to signify the end of the file and I used that to check when I should stop refilling and printing my buffer. It turns out there wasn't for some reason and what would happen is that the syscall would only change until the end of the file in the buffer and leave the rest of the buffer the same, so when I printed it it looked like it was looping itself and at the end I would see part of it wasn't finished, when in reality it did finish but there was some repeat text from the previous buffer refill after. <s>The book I was reading (Programming from the Ground Up) said the syscall would also add a \0 at the end so I can check for that. It was about 32-bit assembly so the syscall might have changed.</s> [Edit 2: Sorry! Turns out I misread the book, see answer.] Now I'm using the return value of the syscall, which is the length of file the system changed in the buffer, in order to check when to stop and to print without repeating parts of the previous buffer.

tl;dr - misunderstood a syscall

Comment: It is supposed to work in the way that you expected it to work, so if it doesn't, something went wrong. Can you share the code that resulted in reading the same data multiple times?

Comment: Did you accidentally reopen the file? That would do it... Post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I realised I misunderstood what happened, I was reaching the end of the file but there was no null byte written to the buffer and I used the null byte to check when the file ended so without it my program continued refilling. See edit. Should I delete this question?

Comment: PGU said it would add a \0 at the end?  I hope the book doesn't say that, and instead you're misinterpreting something.  A POSIX `ssize_t read(int fd, void*, size_t)` system call has never stored bytes into the buffer that weren't actually read from the file.  If the buffer was already filled with zeros, then there will be some that don't get modified on a short or zero-length read.  `read` will *return* `0` as the `ssize_t` return value (in RAX) when there were no bytes to read; that's the normal way to detect EOF.  (Try with `strace cat foo > /dev/null`)

Comment: As for what to do with this question: if there really is wrong info in PGU, or an explanation that can easily be misread / misinterpreted, that's worth having a Q&A about.  I'd recommend rewriting it to focus on that, quoting whatever PGU says. Otherwise it's a duplicate of some Q&As about detecting EOF with `read` system calls. (And feel free to post a self-answer; your last edit should have been posted as an answer to your own question; that's encouraged.) As an open-source book available online, IDK if PGU is still being maintained or accepting updates or at least an errata list.

Comment: Just to be totally clear, nothing has changed regarding how `read()` system calls work.  It dates back to original Unix and has always worked this way, and is standardized by POSIX.  The Linux kernel read system call has always followed the POSIX semantics (especially for the simple case of reading regular files).  See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html for the Linux man page.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sorry, I misread the book, see answer. Thanks for the website, I could only find a list of the arguments for the x86_64 syscalls but not any explanations (which got me confused before when I didn't understand what flags meant for open).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Also I think PGU was clear enough but I didn't want to delete this since I didn't know if you'd be able to see my comments or the answer for the explanation of what happened. Comment after you've read it so I can? I'm pretty sure people can see it after deleting (if it came to their inbox) but I didn't want to risk it.

Comment: If you're using a Linux system, you should have local copies of the man pages.  e.g. `man 2 read` or `man 2 open` will show you the section-2 (system calls) man page for those C functions, with notes on any difference between the glibc wrapper function vs. the raw system call (e.g. for `nice()` or `brk()`).  Most distros include the POSIX man pages as well, not Linux specific, so you do usually need `man 2 fstat` or `man -a fstat`, even for names that don't have a section 1 (user commands) page, otherwise you get the Posix man page in preference to the Linux syscall man page.

Comment: Stack Overflow users with more than 10k rep can see deleted questions (but they don't show up in searches), so I'd still have been able to see your comments if you'd replied and then deleted the question, but it's  better that you didn't.  I'm not sure whether the notifications would still go through.  I wouldn't have been able to reply in that case.

Answer (score 3):

What happened was that I first misread the following about reading lines from Programming from the Ground Up and accidently replaced line with file in my head:

> For an example, let's say that you want to read in a single line of text from a file but you do not know how long that line is. You would then simply read a large number of bytes/characters from the file into a buffer, look for the end-of-line character, and copy all of the characters to that end-of-line character to another location. If you didn't find an end-of-line character, you would allocate another buffer and continue reading. You would probably wind up with some characters left over in your buffer in this case, which you would use as the starting point when you next need data from the file.

When in reality a few paragraphs before it stated that:

> The write system call will give back the number of bytes written in %eax or an error code.

Without mentioning anything about null bytes. If I had read the program, I would have also realised my mistake. Or if I had increased my buffer size to larger than the file's, I think.

For what happened in my code:
I expected there to be a null byte or some other special character to signify the end of the file and I used that to check when I should stop refilling and printing my buffer. The syscall would only change until the end of the file in the buffer and leave the rest of the buffer the same, so when I printed it it would never stop and at the end of each buffer write I would see part of it wasn't finished, when in reality it did finish but there was some repeat text from the previous buffer refill after.

Well, technically I realise now the buffer only gets refilled once at the end, after that the reads don't change the buffer at all and I'm just rewriting that last buffer until I stop the program.

Comment: Ah, yes, line-oriented I/O is something programs often want, but the OS doesn't know where line boundaries are so you can only read chunks of bytes.  One of the major purposes of the C stdio library functions like `fgets`.  OSes do know where the end of a *file* is, so that can be reflected in system-call return values directly.  (And obtainable via `fstat(fd, &statbuf)`